# How to extract object values from localstorage to each row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to loop through my locally stored objects(JSON.stringify) and then print them out to each row(html). Each row takes one object and prints the values to each column in that row.
I don't know if this helps but there it is it might help you have a better understanding of what i'm trying to explain.

```js
var table2 = document.getElementById('table');
for(var l = 0; l < localStorage.getItem("Rows"); l += 1) {
 var tableinLoadRow = document.getElementById('table').insertRow(l);
 for(var t = 0; t < 9; t += 1) {
  var tableinLoadCell = tableinLoadRow.insertCell(t);
 }
 for(x in localStorage) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x));
  for(i in obj) {
   if(i === "ModelMake") {
    table2.rows[l].cells[0].innerHTML = obj[i];

   }
  }
 }
}
```

I can't put the whole code application's code because it's more than 200 lines i don't think anybody would want to go through all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple "Vanilla.js" example ([JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/simipuxabi/1/edit?html,js,output)) that illustrates the process. Do take note that this example will not output properly if the properties of your data are not ordered exactly the same or if your objects have an inconsistent number of properties. That would require some more specific engineering.

*HTML*

```
<div>
  <table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var data = [
    { name: 'Bob', age: 40, gender: 'M' },
    { name: 'James', age: 26, gender: 'M' },
    { name: 'Susan', age: 37, gender: 'F' }
  ];

  var table, row, cell;

  table = document.getElementById('table');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // insert a new row at the end of the table
    row = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var prop in data[i]) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerText = data[i][prop];
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. I'm using JQuery to clone DOM nodes (table rows), but if you really needed to do that in [vanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/), you could.

Note that the code will not work in this snippet, because of XSS concerns, but you should be able to copy/paste it into an environment you control, and it should work there.

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: "bob", color: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "carl", color: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "sally", color: "lavender"}
];

window.localStorage.Rows = JSON.stringify(data);

function addRow(row) {
  var tr = $('#cloneme').clone().prop('hidden',false);
  tr.find('.id').text(row.id);
  tr.find('.name').text(row.name);
  tr.find('.color').text(row.color);
  tr.appendTo('#table');
}

var dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.Rows );

dataFromLocalStorage.forEach(function(thisrow){
  addRow(thisrow);
});
```

```css
#table { 
  border-spacing: 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
th {
  background-color: silver;
  padding: .5em;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid silver;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>favourite color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="cloneme" hidden>
    <td class="id">{{id}}</td>
    <td class="name">{{name}}</td>
    <td class="color">{{colour}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that `localStorage` does not natively support a `Rows` property. You must be using some additional library.

Comment: `localStorage` is simply key/value storage. You can use the verbose methods ( `localstorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem()` ) or more directly: (`localStorage.foo = 5;` or `localStorage.Rows = JSON.stringify( someArrayOrObject );`)